# Python3: List of strings, where strings having variable letters (not all letters at not all positions)

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, replace

first some biological background, so you understand my question. In biology, DNA-sequences can contain motifs, which are recognized by enzymes or proteins. Those motifs are strings, like "GACTGC". Analyses can reveal, whether a position in the motif is "conserved" or not.

Enzymes might recognize "GACTGC" best, but may also recognize "CACTGC" or even "TTCTGC". So, some positions may vary.

I have the following situation:
I want to create a list of permutations, with motifs, that could be recognized. In order to do so, I have the info:

Best recognition: GACTGC

Bases, also possible:

```
GACTGC
A  C G
T    A
```

which means, at first position, there could alsoe be A or T, at 4th there could be a C etc., but at 2nd position, the A is conserved, nothing else is possible.

I can generate a list with one base varying for each position, by turning the "best-fit" motif into a list of letters and replacing one letter, joining and appending to my list (doing that for each position). So it basically is hard coded.
It worked out, since I changed any position, no matter what motif was entered. **But now I want to change specific positions to specific letters and store specific permutations only, depending on the motif.**

**So, I am looking for the shortest/fastest/maybe smartest way, to pass the information of the positions and their valid letters, and how to create the permutations for one and two variable positions.**

**please note**: I will try to post my code in an answer or via an edit, somehow copy-paste and then ctrl+k on the marked code does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be a way to solve this problem with itertools, but I think it can be done quick enough with a self-made permutation function:

```
example_bases = [
  "GAT",  # options for first position
  "A",    # options for second position
  "C",    # ...
  "TC",
  "G",
  "CGA"
]

def permutate(bases, results, depth=0, current_result=""):
"""Create permutations of a list of strings

All resulting strings have the length len(bases), and there will be a total
of mult([len(options) for option in bases]) total results, e.g.:
["abc", "de", "fghi"] -> 3 * 2 * 4 -> 24

:param bases: List of possible options for a base
:param results: The object which will contain all valid results
:param depth: Internal counter for current recursive depth 
:param current_result: Internal variable to keep track of progress 
"""
  if depth == len(bases):
    results.append(current_result)
  else:
    for base in bases[depth]:
      permutate(bases, results, depth+1, current_result+base)

example_results = []
permutate(example_bases, example_results)
for sequence in example_results:
  print(sequence)
```

prints the 18 possible combinations for this particular example:

```
GACTGC
GACTGG
GACTGA
GACCGC
GACCGG
GACCGA
AACTGC
AACTGG
AACTGA
AACCGC
AACCGG
AACCGA
TACTGC
TACTGG
TACTGA
TACCGC
TACCGG
TACCGA
```

If recursion is not your thing or you have a question about the code, please feel free to ask.

Comment: thank you so much! your presumtion is correct, recursion is not my thing, but I think, I was able to trace it back! I could have never made it up on my own, but I hope I will remember it, when I face likewise problems in the future :)

Comment: Happy to help, best of luck =)

Comment: I understood it like this: The combinations are made from the strings provided for the positions. If only one letter is encountered, it is "added" and we can proceed to the next position. But if more letters are encountered, it is done for the first option of the letters, it is proceeded to the end, and in the next step, we are at the next option of the letters. This is done, until we do it for the last option and proceed to the next position

Comment: Correct. I think if you keep a mental note of what value the depth counter has during the different stages of the code execution, the results are not too surprising.
For me personally, recursion is easiest to understand if I can picture it in my mind as a Depth First Search https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search